# Netbeans: Deletes my project when deploying

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, netbeans

It seems that when I try to deploy my JSP project, it suddenly removes the whole project.

Here is my debug log:

```
ant -f D:\\tomcat\\webapps\\WebApplication1 -Dnb.internal.action.name=debug -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -DforceRedeploy=false -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true -Dis.debugged=true -Dbrowser.context=D:\\tomcat\\webapps\\WebApplication1 debug
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
debug:
connect-debugger:
Undeploying ...
undeploy?path=/WebApplication1
OK - Undeployed application at context path [/WebApplication1]
In-place deployment at D:\tomcat\webapps\WebApplication1\build\web
D:\tomcat\webapps\WebApplication1\build\web\META-INF\context.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
D:\tomcat\webapps\WebApplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1152: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I am using Netbeans 8.2, Tomcat 8.5.16, jdk1.8.0_131.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do I interpret this correctly that you are developing (e.g. in Netbeans) within tomcat/webapps/WebApplication1? You shouldn't do this, for precisely the reason you're observing. Rather create your project elsewhere, then have Netbeans (or Ant or whatever build tool) deploy to Tomcat.

This is the same reason why no webapplication should save uploaded data in its own directory: It might disappear on redeployment/upgrade of your webapplication, because the server assumes that an undeployment means that you don't want the files any more. Have them elsewhere, and everything is fine.